# Bluealsa not discovering nor connecting with iPhone

Tags: bluetooth

I am having a problem in trying to get my iPhone able to discover the raspberry pi as well as getting the raspberrypi to pair with the iPhone.

I am using bluealsa as pulseaudio got replaced, however I can't get nothing working.

Do I need to enable some A2DP profiling with bluealsa? Is it's default able to connect to Bluetooth classic devices?